# has_many relationship with uniqness couples

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, join

i have trouble to user uniqness couples in my app...

I have users witch can be linked to so some contacts.
I use a relation table to do my links (witch has a level attribute also - for different level of relations)

So i have users, contacts and relationships.
My problem is that the couple contact_id and user_id has to be uniq (they can be linked only once).

contact.rb

> has_many :relations, :dependent => :destroy
>
> has_many :users, :through => :relations, :uniq => true

user.rb

> has_many :relations, :dependent => :destroy
>
> has_many :contacts, :through => :relations, :uniq => true

relation.rb

> belongs_to :user
>
> belongs_to :contact

I dont know if i have to use foreign_key or whatever, i just need something simple :)

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :contact
      validates_uniqueness_of :contact_id, :scope => :user_id

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:scope` option on your uniqueness validation. Something like `validates_uniqueness_of :contact, :scope => :user` means that for a given user, there won't be duplicate contacts. So if you validate each of your attributes scoped to the other one, I think it results in what you want. There might be a better way (that I obviously don't know though).

Comment: Yep, sorry. I don't use it very often, and forgot you have to mention the actual key.